# protractor setup in visual studio 2013 + type script

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013, protractor

I want to run protractor scripts (conf.ts, spec.ts(jasmine framework)) in visual studio 2013 type script.I am not very sure which solution i should create in vs and where to add the ts files. can you please guide.

Comment: @KishanPatel that's for visual studio code not visual studio 2013.

Comment: Removed the comment @toskv

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've worked in VS 2013 so I'm not sure these templates are even available but if you have the Typescript templates installed you can just add an `HTML Application with TypeScript` project and just delete the unnecessary files. I've also used a class library project and set it up to have TypeScript Build capabilities and it works fine. I like to keep my unit tests next to the files they are testing but I keep my protractor tests in an entirely different project. For me, it's a personal preference and it cuts down on the clutter in my webapp project. You could just use a different directory if that's easier. It's entirely up to you.

[image]

Then you can organize your `.ts` files in there as you see fit. Here is a screenshot of how I've organized one of my projects.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou! i have tried the same as above. when i run my conf.ts, getting errors like,Cannot find name 'browser;cannot find element; cannot find by; any solution for this?

Comment: Are you importing these in your test files where you need them? `import {browser, by, element} from 'protractor'`?

Comment: thankyou..i have added and the error is gone but i am still stuck with below errors. can you please help. errors: 1.Build: Cannot find name 'exports'. in conf.ts 2.Error 2 Build: A class may only extend another class in jasmine.d.ts

Comment: I would need to see your config and the code that is causing the jasmine error to know what is wrong.

Comment: ok thanks..i will attach it. but i can run successfully the same in webstrom or directly from command prompt. so, the issue is not with conf or spec file. may be i am missing some configuration.